Is Hebrews 10:26 describing a violation of the NEW Covenant?
Hebrews 10:26-28

26 For if we keep on sinning willfully after we have received the knowledge of the truth, there no longer remains a sacrifice for sins, 27  but only a terrifying expectation of judgment and a fury of fire about to devour the enemies of God. 28 Anyone who rejected the Torah of Moses dies without compassion on the word of two or three witnesses.

See willful sin is the same as intentional sin or defiant sin, in the Torah it says those who committed this sin had to bear their own guilt (Defiantly going against a commandment, relating to ceremonial instructions). However, I was stating that when it came to the moral law most of these sins are done intentionally or willfully like a murderer kills someone with hatred in their heart and intent. Then perhaps this willful sin relates to defiantly sinning as in violating the New Covenant. I don't know if it is a willful sin or that you continue to sin are these sins or is this a type of defiant sin or sins like faithlessness or apostasy? So is this describing a violation of the New  Covenant?

What do I think ? I think that the question is so unclear that I do not know what question you are actually seeking an answer to. Are you just stating a (rather obscure) theory and asking for positive or negative responses ? If so, that is not the purpose of this site.

Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others. I also recommend going through the Help Center's sections on both asking and answering questions.

I’m voting to close this question because this is a mini-sermon and not a question

I’m voting to close this question because it does not conform to the principles of seeking a hermeneutical answer.

It is okay I sort of forgot my own question, I am all over the place with this.

The question is worded much better now, but it's still not very clear exactly what it is asking. ¶ To answer the Title question literally, the answer is "no, it's about the old testament". But it is there only to set the context for the following verses, which do talk about the new testament: "Of how much sorer punishment, suppose ye, shall he be thought worthy, who hath trodden under foot the Son of God, and …?". Willful sinning in light of Jesus's sacrifice is far worse than it was under the Torah.

I think there is an important question here, even though it is not asked clearly. I hope it can be rescued.

The text in question reads:

"For if we sin wilfully after that we have received the knowledge of
the truth, there remaineth no more sacrifice for sins." Hebrews 10:26
A.V.

The question asks if that verse violates the Torah, and quotes two sections of it, one in Numbers and the other in Deuteronomy. However, the answer has to be "No" because the writer is not dealing with any sacrifices in the Torah.
Context around that verse in Hebrews shows he speaks of the once-for-all-time, perfect sacrifice for sin Jesus had accomplished. See verses 16-18. Christ has entered into heaven itself, with his blood, so that sacrifice for sin is complete. The readers of that letter were being pointed to that one sacrifice of Christ on the cross, not to any of the Old Covenant sacrifices. He only refers to that as an illustration that exemplifies the awful seriousness of rejecting the sacrifice of "the Lamb of God that takes away the sin of the world" (John 1:29 & 35).
The one sacrifice of Christ is the one and only sacrifice that completely deals with sin itself, and our individual sins. When the verse in question is read with that understanding (of the context) the matter is cleared up. Hebrews 10:26 is not dealing with any violations of the Old Covenant. It deals with the one sacrifice for sins accomplished by Christ on the cross.

I am sorry I meant the Covenant as the New Covenant, is that describing the breaking of the New Covenant? I forgot to put New.
